# What is antonym of "update"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms, technical

The antonym of "upgrade" is "downgrade", quite broadly used.

What is the antonym of "update"?

Update:
Though, I hoped for something like "un-update" because reverting or uninstalling updates are much lengthier.
Update2:
After having further answers about "Restore", et al, I decided to restore the phrase from my original update.

> Yes, I can revert updates (uninstall
>   service packs, hotfixes or restore
>   the operating system to a previous
>   state/image)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you update your browser, you might want to *rollback* the update or to *undo* it.
Mostly used in database management, I often hear/read about rollback of driver updates or program installs.

Comment: :) Glad to have helped

Comment: "Backdate" usually means to change the date of a document, but not its content. "Restore" might be possible here.

Comment: @Mahnax you gotta be kiddin' ?

Comment: @mplungjan Uh, there was no period. I added one. Is that a problem?

Comment: I know - I can see how the lack of a period must have made you desperate to edit my 1 year old post ;))) SRSLY?

Answer (score 13):

It depends.

- If you just don't update stuff, you *let it become obsolete/old/out-of-date*, let it *age*, *olden*, or *dust*. A stronger and more colloquial expression would be, you *let it rot*. However, the most straightforward thing to say would be, you just *don't update* it.
- If you actively perform the opposite of updating, you *make it old* or *revert it to an older state*. A more eccentric word would be, you *antique* it.

Answer (score 8):

If you don't update it, you leave it as it is, fail to maintain it, or simply ignore it. There is no "downdate" you can perform.

You could, however, "revert" it, as we do for edits on this site.

Comment: Usually it is not me, it is by auto-update

Answer (score 3):

I think "date" could be seen as an antonym for "update." To date something can mean *to assign to a particular time*. If something is dated, in this sense, it is not, or no longer, updated. Similarly, something "outdated" could be considered the opposite of something updated.

Comment: Sorry but this is at best a very exotic suggestion.  No native English-speaking engineer I know would assume that "dating" something had anything to do with reversing an update.

Comment: From _NSOED_: **date** _v. t. & i._ Mark as or bear evidence of being of a certain date; make, be, or become outdated. **Update** _v. t._ Bring up to date. Sure, not common usage in technical circles, but worth a down vote?

Comment: @Callithumpian: I think so, and I don't often downvote.  This answer could seriously mislead a non-native speaker.

Comment: ...thereby demonstrating my point nicely.

Comment: @Rhodri: I certainly do not want to mislead, but I would like to defend my line of thinking in finding an antonym for update that could be used in everyday speech or writing where _rollback_ would make no sense. Would you also label these synonyms of _date_ misleading: **antiquate**, **archaize**, **obsolesce**, **obsolete**?

Comment: @Callithumpian: as antonyms of "update", yes I would label them misleading.  As antonyms of "modernize", on the other hand, they would fit very nicely.  There is a fairly significant difference of meaning there, though it may not be obvious from the dictionary definition.

Answer (score 1):

The only antonyms reported by [Thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/update) are *antique*, and *make old*.

Comment: or putting piles of dust into my computer or applying other techniques used in restoring antiquaries? This is disappointing answer for a programmer. I wonder why had you removed the "technical" tag from my original question by your editing?