# Word for the situation "Get back to the previous situation"

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there is a single word that denote the situation of getting back to the previous level?

Like I want to say, "It is good that something positive had happened but now all X(the word meaning get back to previous level)"

Edit:
I would explain a situation, say, Some new technology came like Mobile App so people started using it, but with passing time some people dont want to use the App and go back to how they were doing before.

Comment: What does "level" mean to you here?  Something "good" happened so the "level" (whatever it is) goes up, and now you want everybody to ignore the good thing?

Comment: I want to ignore the good thing and return to zero

Comment: See also http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/15526/what-is-antonym-of-update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Revert` might be what you are looking for?

it means exactly "go back to a previous state"

you also have downgrading which litteraly means get down a grade

or fall back (it does have a negative connotation)

Comment: Edited my question. May you help on that?

Comment: Yes, it's revert to the old ways

Comment: It's still not exactly what I was thinking, but its too close. Thanks!

Comment: @Manu "To revert to a previous state" is also known as "returning to the status quo ante," but that may be too formal or legalistic.